# Arrow annotation that moves along the X-axis in winforms chart

Tags: winforms, charts

I am animating a winforms chart using a trackBar and a timer which is working great. I want to  show the market level on this animation. The market level is just a point on the X-Axis. I have 4 chart areas that all correspond to each other.

I have managed to achieve this using a line annotation by placing the following code in a loop looping through the chart areas (I clear the annotations collection every frame of the animation):

```
            VerticalLineAnnotation line = new VerticalLineAnnotation();

            line.IsInfinitive = true;
            line.ClipToChartArea = chartArea.Name;
            line.LineWidth = 3;
            line.LineColor = Color.MediumSeaGreen;
            line.AxisX = chartArea.AxisX;
            line.X = marketLevel;

            chrOI.Annotations.Add(line);
```

But instead of a vertical line, I would prefer to just have an arrow that points to the relevant position on the X-Axis.

So currently I have:

[image: line annotation]

But I would prefer something like this mock example I made in paint:

[image: mock up using arrow annotation]

Any ideas?

Comment: Use the PostPaint event to draw whatever you want.

Comment: I would rather use an annotations like I have above, but I'm not sure how to place them correctly. I saw this regarding the paint events: http://support2.dundas.com/OnlineDocumentation/WebChart2005/Annotations.html but I didn't really follow it

Comment: I know it is old, but did you find any solution to your query? I also want to display an arrowhead using arrow type annotations but am a bit confused.

Comment: @Candy I don't think I did, but I can't imagine using winforms and annotations etc is still a relevant thing to do. I think it was already quite outdated when I did it a decade ago. I'm sure there's a much better, modern way for you to create your charts